# An static Controller Handler to manage the methods that are used in controllers...¿good?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an static class with methods that are used in controller actions, the idea was not to put the logic inside controller actions so an example of this class is:

```
namespace MyTestProject.Infrastructure.Handler
{
public static class ControllerHandler
{
    public static string GetUserName(GetLoggedUserResponse user)
    {
        string username = string.Empty;

        if (user != null)
        {
            username = user.Nombre;
        }

        return username;
    }
    private static List<Menu> GetVisibleChildMenus(GetLoggedUserResponse user, int idMenu, bool tab)
    {
        return user.MenusPerfiles.Where(mp => mp.Menu.IdPadre == idMenu
                                              && mp.Menu.Visible.Value
                                              && mp.Menu.Tab.Value == tab)
                                                     .Select(mp => mp.Menu)
                                                     .OrderBy(m => m.Orden)
                                                     .ToList();
    }

    public static List<Navbar> GetNavBar(GetLoggedUserResponse user, PathString requestPath)
    {
        List<Navbar> navbar = new List<Navbar>();

        if (user != null)
        {
            //menu correspondiente a la pantalla actual
            Menu menu = user.MenusPerfiles.Where(mp => mp.Menu.Ruta.StartsWith("/") && requestPath.StartsWithSegments(mp.Menu.Ruta))
                                          .Select(mp => mp.Menu)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();

            if (menu != null)
            {
                //hijos en modo tab
                List<Menu> menus = GetVisibleChildMenus(user, menu.Id.Value, true);

                menus.ForEach(m =>
                {
                    //hijos del menu tab (se mostraran en forma de lista desplegable)
                    List<Menu> menusTab = GetVisibleChildMenus(user, m.Id.Value, false);
                    var navbarMenus = new List<NavbarMenu>();

                    menusTab.ForEach(mt =>
                    {
                        navbarMenus.Add(new NavbarMenu
                        {
                            link = mt.Ruta,
                            title = mt.Nombre
                        });
                    });

                    navbar.Add(new Navbar
                    {
                        title = m.Nombre,
                        icon_css = m.CssIcon,
                        class_css = menusTab == null || menusTab.Count() > 0 ? "" : "dropdown",
                        link = m.Ruta,                           
                        menus = navbarMenus
                    });
                });
            }
        }

        return navbar;
    }

    public static Sidebar GetSideBar(GetLoggedUserResponse user)
    {
        Sidebar sidebar = null;

        if (user != null)
        {
            sidebar = new Sidebar();

            List<Menu> menus = user.MenusPerfiles.Where(mp => mp.Menu.Visible.Value && !mp.Menu.IdPadre.HasValue).Select(mp => mp.Menu).OrderBy(m => m.Orden).ToList();

            menus.ForEach(m =>
            {
                var sidebarMenus = new Menus();

                //hijos en modo tab
                List<Menu> childMenus = GetVisibleChildMenus(user, m.Id.Value, false);

                childMenus.ForEach(cm =>
                {
                    sidebarMenus.Add(new SidebarMenu {title = cm.Nombre, url = cm.Ruta, position = cm.Orden.Value });
                });

                sidebar.Add(new SidebarButton
                {
                    title = m.Nombre,
                    icon_css = m.CssIcon,
                    position = m.Orden.Value,
                    id = m.Id.Value,
                    visible = true,
                    menus = sidebarMenus
                });
            });                
        }
        else
        {
            sidebar = new Sidebar {
               new SidebarButton {
                   title = "Dashboard", icon_css = "s7-monitor", position = 1, id = 1, visible = true,
                   menus = new Menus(){
                        new SidebarMenu { title = "Main Dashboard", url = "/", position = 1 }}}               
            };
        }

        return sidebar;
    }

    public static ReportViewModel GetReport(string reportId, string accessToken)
    {
        GetReportResponse report = ApiHandler.GetReport(reportId, accessToken);

        var reportsViewModel = new ReportViewModel() { Reports = new List<Report>() };

        report.Reports.ForEach(r =>
        {
            reportsViewModel.Reports.Add(new Report { Id = r.ReportId,
                                                      EmbedUrl = r.EmbedUrl,
                                                      AccessToken = r.AccessToken,
                                                      VisibleScreenSize = r.VisibleScreenSize,
                                                      HiddenScreenSize = r.HiddenScreenSize });
        });

        return reportsViewModel;
    }

    public static async Task<GetNotificationResponse> GetNotifications(string all, string accessToken)
    {
        GetNotificationResponse result = await ApiHandler.GetNotifications(all, accessToken);

        return result;
    }
```

...

But it seems to me like a bad idea because this class will have more than one responsability this is correct? So it's better to split this class? in that case what I don't like is that in controller actions we have to deal to instance a lot of classes and I like the idea that we have a "single point" or something like this that helps from controller to access all this methods what do yout think? there are any design pattern for this?.

Also this kind of methods (get user name, build menus, get user notifications) are methods to put under infrastructure namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this static class more like a *library* for common methods helpful for a controller.  It's certainly not uncommon for developers to create such static *libraries* of commonly used methods and often the library will contain methods that might have little in common.

However in this case since all the methods are intended to be used by a Controller you could instead created a class, perhaps called `Base Controller` that inherits from `Controller` and implements these methods (not as statics). Then you can have the controllers in your website inherit from `BaseController`.  This will make these convenience methods available to your controller without having to reference a static class.  This approach is also widely used and could be a better choice in for your particular case.